# If there is a way to deploy jdbc driver using Arquillian

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to run the test by using embedded wildFly. I want Arquillian to deploy the jdbc driver before test. If it is possible, or I forced to deploy this driver manualy to the server before testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i had the same problem like you- trying to get our jpa-unit tests run with arquillian and using an embedded wildfly for it.

I´ve resolved it partially- for the moment i was able to add the MSSQL-driver to the embedded wildfly. My current problem is to add a datasource, to connect to the database...

But here´s my part of the POM, which extracts the wildfly to the /target folder and then copying the db-driver to the standalone/deployments folder of the embedded wildfly. So the driver get registered succesfull (I´ve checked this in the management console of the embedded wildfly):

I hope this helps you. Maybe you have a solution how to add the datasource for the embedded wildfly? (If you need this too)

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                        <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>copy-db-driver</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.2206.100</version>
                        <outputDirectory>target/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I am trying to solve the same problem: Deploy jdbc driver on wildfly embedded. Your pom-snippet looks promising. However, I get an error saying that the artiface is not found; it is searched in the ../libs directory. But I would like to take it from my local .m2 repository. How can I get that?